# Converting Flattened JSON to Dataframe in Python 2.7

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, dataframe, flatten

I am trying to read some data using REST API and write that on a DB table. I have written the below code. But unfortunately, I am kind of stuck with the flattened JSON. Can you please help with a way to convert JSON to Data frame.

Code

```
 import requests
 import json
 import pandas
 from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
 from flatten_json import flatten

 j_username = 'ABCD'
 j_password = '12456'
 query = '"id = 112233445566"'
 print query
 r=requests.get('Url' % query, auth= (j_username,j_password))

 print r.json()
 first_response = r.json()
 string_data = json.dumps(r.json())
 normalized_r = json_normalize(r.json())
 print flatten(r.json())
 r_flattened = flatten(r.json())
 r_flattened_str = json.dumps(flatten(r.json()))
 print type (flatten(r.json()))
```

Flattened JSON Output is as below

```
      {
     'data_0_user-35': u'Xyz',
'data_0_user-34': None,
'data_0_user-37': u'CC',
'data_0_user-36': None,
'data_0_user-31': u'Regular',
'data_0_user-33': None, 
'data_0_user-32': None, 
'data_0_target-rcyc_id': 0101,
'data_0_to-mail': None,
'data_0_closing-version': None, 
'data_0_user-44': None, 
'data_0_test-reference': None,
'data_0_request-server': None, 
'data_0_target-rcyc_type': u'regular type',
'data_0_project': None,
'data_0_user-01': u'Application Name',
'data_0_user-02': None,
'data_0_user-03': None, .......
 .......
```

......
 ..... }

Expected Output is

```
               data_0_user-35   data_0_user-34  data_0_user-37  .........

                 XYZ               None            CC             ........
```

Comment: That's no longer JSON -- that just looks like a dictionary. You probably could cut out some steps in the middle there, but based on what you have, have you tried calling `pandas.from_dict(r_flattened)`?

Comment: I have tried that now and got below error message

'code'
             print pandas.from_dict(r_flattened)
             AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'from_dict' 'code'

Comment: Apologies, that should have been `pandas.DataFrame.from_dict()`.

Comment: That has given me the following error

'ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index'

so I tried this one  'print pandas.DataFrame(r_flattened.items())' and it has given me the below output

Comment: `                            0                          1
                        data_0_user-35                 Xyz
     1                data_0_user-34                 None
     2                 data_0_user-37                   CC
     3                 data_0_user-36                 None
     4                 data_0_user-31             Regular
     5                 data_0_user-33                 None
     6                 data_0_user-32                 None
     7          data_0_target-rcyc_id                 0101 `

Answer (score 0):

I finally cracked this. This code will read the data from a REST API and convert that into a data frame and eventually write in a Oracle database. Thanks to my friend and some of the wonderful people in the community whose answers helped me to come to this.

```
        import requests
        from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
        import datetime as dt
        import pandas as pd
        import cx_Oracle

        date = dt.datetime.today().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
        date = "'%s'" % date
        query2 = '"creation-time=%s"' % date
        r = requests.get('url?query=%s' % query2,
             auth=('!username', 'password#'))
        response_data_json = r.json()
        response_data_normalize = json_normalize(response_data_json['data'])
        subset = response_data_normalize.loc[:, ('value1', 'value2')]
        Counter = subset['value1'].max()
        converted_value = getattr(Counter, "tolist", lambda x=Counter: x)()
        frame = pd.DataFrame()
        for i in range(2175, converted_value + 1): #2175 is just a reference number to start the comparison from....specific to my work
            id = '"id = %s"' % i
            r = requests.get('url?&query=%s' % id, auth=('!username', 'password#'))
            response_data_json1 = r.json()
            response_data_normalize1 = json_normalize(response_data_json1['data'])
            sub = response_data_normalize1.loc[:, ('value1', 'value2', 'value3',  'value4')]
            frame = frame.append(sub, ignore_index=True)


        con = cx_Oracle.connect('USERNAME','PASSWORD',cx_Oracle.makedsn('HOSTNAME',PORTNUMBER,'SERVICENAME'))

        cur = con.cursor()
        rows = [tuple(x) for x in frame.values]
        print rows
        cur.executemany('''INSERT INTO TABLENAME(Value1, Value2,Value3,Value4) VALUES (:1,:2,:3,:4)''',rows)
        con.commit()
        cur.close()
        con.close()
```